# Automatically Combine Values using Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

I currently have a dataset called test.csv with the columns:

```
location time
```

It consists of a number of records, which may be for the same location. ie. there may be two records where the location is Paris but the time is different and I wish to add them and then plot them as one.

I wish to combine the values of time for all where the value of location is the same when plotting to a bar chart using Google Chart. Currently I have written this, but am unsure how to continue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">

 <title>Google Graph and CSV</title>
 <meta name="description" content="test">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // load the visualisation API
  google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function drawVisualization() {
   $.get("test.csv", function(csvString) {
      var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
      var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: 'BarChart',
         containerId: 'crt_ertdlyYY',
         dataTable: data,
         options:{
            title: 'Room Occupancy for',
            titleTextStyle : {color: 'grey', fontSize: 16},
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: { position: "none" },
            width:400,
            height:600,
         }
      });
      crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
   });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)
</script>

<div id="crt_ertdlyYY"></div>
```

This produces the following visualisation: [Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdpx0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to aggregate the total for each location

```
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [0],
  [{
    column: 1,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Total'
  }]
);
```

then use the grouped data on the chart

```
var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
   chartType: 'BarChart',
   containerId: 'crt_ertdlyYY',
   dataTable: aggData,  // <-- use agg data
   options:{
      title: 'Room Occupancy for',
      titleTextStyle : {color: 'grey', fontSize: 16},
      bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
      legend: { position: "none" },
      width:400,
      height:600,
   }
});
```

**EDIT**

a `modifier` function can be used to combine locations with different *cases*

```
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [{
    column: 0,
    modifier: function (value) {
      return value.toUpperCase();
    },
    type: 'string',
    label: 'Location'
  }],
  [{
    column: 1,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Total'
  }]
);
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. Another problem is that some of the locations have different cases eg. Paris and paris. How can I standardise the case?